# Issue to resume Android Activity programmatically from background

Tags: java, android

I tried to resume Android Activity programmatically from the background but when I press the home button the activity goes background after five seconds the activity launch again. working well with the back button and recent app button.

Why its delay for five seconds to relaunch??

API level is 19 and Android version is 4.4.2 (KitKat)

Here is Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test.drawtoptest">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Main2Activity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:parentActivityName=".Main2Activity"
            >
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  MyTimerTask myTimerTask;
    Timer timer;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    }
  public void test(){
      Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
        myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
 class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            test();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        if (timer == null) {
            myTimerTask = new MyTimerTask();
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(myTimerTask, 50, 50);
        }
        super.onPause();

    }
}
```